Plotly not showing in colab
I was using colab and trying to use plotly but it doesn't show anything no error but no plot as well, it just expand the output as it's showing it but nothing. I though maybe it theme extension but I uninstalled it and nothing.
import cufflinks as cf
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()

df_stocks = px.data.stocks()
px.line(df_stocks, x='date', y='GOOG', labels={'x':'Date', 'y':'Price'})


From your code above you didn't explicitly ensure the renderer you are using. The renderer lets the Plotly know which environment to display the plot. You must pass it as a string either as a colab or notebook.

figure = px.line(df_stocks, x='date', y='GOOG', labels={'x':'Date', 'y':'Price'})
figure.show(renderer='colab') # or use this instead; figure.show(renderer='notebook')




figure = px.line(df_stocks, x='date', y='GOOG', labels={'x':'Date', 'y':'Price'})
figure.show(renderer='colab')
didn't work as well its still expands the output but no plot at all

Have you solved it yet? Sorry for my late reply, I am just seeing your reply now.

No sadly I didn't I just left the problem couldn't find much about it.

which environment (IDE) are you working with? Please share your error traceback from your terminal if there is any?  Use print() to debug most of your work I believe it will give us more information to work on.

Also, ensure to update your plotly - !pip install plotly --upgrade
